# Как узнать, есть ли родитель у элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

У меня есть необходимость при клике на элемент добавлять родительскому элементу новый класс. Как добавлять классы я знаю, а вот как найти родительский элемент? Будет круто, если ещё и можно будет отслеживать тэг родительского элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this.parentNode != null, this.parentNode.tagName);
});
```

```html
<div>
<button id="test">Click</button>
</div>
```

---

> При клике на картинку или на текст возвращает undefined,

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(this.parentNode);
});
```

```html
<div>
<button id="test">Click</button>
</div>
```

---

У параметра `e` (`Event`) нет свойства `parentNode`.

```
console.log(e.target.parentNode.tagName);
```

Comment: При клике на картинку или на текст возвращает undefined, хотя оба этих элемента находятся в li.

Comment: @НикитаПопов Потому что Вы неправильнo обращаетесь к родительскому элементу.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно свойство [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement), а для определения тега — [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

Comment: При клике на картинку или на текст возвращает undefined, хотя оба этих элемента находятся в li.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно привести пример кода, который вы используете. Пока вы получаете общие ответы на общий вопрос.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ey48uk6w/
Клик производится на область 'RUB'

Comment: Лучше добавьте ссылку с объяснениями в вопрос. Или можно задать другой вопрос вместо этого, поэтому что, судя по количеству кода, это уже и правда другой вопрос.

Comment: @НикитаПопов У параметра `e` (`Event`) нет свойства `parentNode`. `console.log(e.target.parentNode.tagName);`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.parentNode; // возвращает <html> элемент
document.body.parentElement; // возвращает <html> элемент

document.documentElement.parentNode; // возвращает Document node
document.documentElement.parentElement; // возвращает null (<html> не имеет родительского node)
```